# How can determine servlet path at runtime?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, path, context.xml

I have some `.class` file in a directory in a default package. Each file has a class  and this class has a `@Service` annotation and method have `@Operation` annotation.

I know how to read annotations at run time but these file are .class file and I don't know how to read them. 
otherwise I want to write each`Service` annotation at path in `context.xml` file and write each operation in url-pattern in `web.xml` file at runtime . How I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put classes in your directory into classpath, then you can easily access them via ClassLoader API:

```
Class<?> clazz = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
```

Now the problem here is that you do not know class names and you basically want to scan them all. So you can use one of the libraries out there available. For example, Guava provides API to scan class path via [ClassPath](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) helper utility:

```
ClassPath classPath = ClassPath.from(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
for (ClassPath.ClassInfo classInfo : classPath.getTopLevelClasses()) {
    Class<?> clazz = classInfo.load();
    // process annotations here
}
```

Comment: I use second part that you said . and i use  System.out.println( "Classpath = " + classPath.toString()); sintax to see what is the classPath .the output is Classpath = com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath@1663380 . I want to chang classpath to server packag in src . what should i do ?

Comment: when running your program pass directories you need to java process : `java -classpath <dir> ...`